# How to change order in flex box with just CSS

Tags: css

Isn't there a way to change the order of the children of a flex box with just CSS?

`<div> flex 2 </div> <div>`
`flex 3`
`</div>`
`<div style="flex-order:-1"> flex 1 </div>`

Comment: [CSS 'order' property MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

Comment: [Also: Ordering Flex-Items in general MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the property `order`
`.div1 { order: 0; }`

But to make it work you should set order to all childrens

Also you should now: `0` for first position, and `1`, `2` and so on for other positions

Comment: The default order for flex elements is 0, no need to set that.

Comment: I also saw that I can use -1

Answer (score 2):

You can use `order` attribute example:

```css
order: 1;
order: 2;
order: 4;
order: 3;
```

You can find more here in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

Comment: I tried that but the matter is that changes the full order of the flex box, I want to set special orders for children

Comment: @VisirMGEntertainment You can use `order` I updated the answer so you can order them as pleased.

Answer (score 2):

Having an HTML code like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-2">Flex 2</div>
  <div class="item-3">Flex 3</div>
  <div class="item-1">Flex 1</div>
</div>
```

If you want to change the order of a specific item, you can use the *order* attribute like this:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.item-1 {
  order: 1;
}

.item-2 {
  order: 2;
}

.item-3 {
  order: 3;
}
```

This code will reorder elements: Flex 1 - Flex 2 - Flex 3.

But, if you want to change the order of all items at same time, simply use *flex-direction* on the wrapper:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

This code will reorder elements: Flex 1 - Flex 3 - Flex 2.